# CSS support in the Evolution e-mail client

Tags: html, css, email, html-email

This question may be more appropriate for another SE site, if so apologies. Basically we are writing an HTML email template. It's just a simple table layout with some `td` styling and text styling (`a`'s, `b`'s and `span`'s). All CSS is inline.

The background styles to the td's are rendered fine. But all text styling CSS seems to be completely ignored in Evolution. I've even tried the old-school:

```
<font color="red">blah</font>
```

But to no avail. Is it possible to style text for the [Evolution e-mail client](http://projects.gnome.org/evolution/)?

Thanks

Richard.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like it does not support CSS at all:

> If an HTML mail is not correctly
>   displayed in Evolution it might be
>   that the formatting is specified as
>   CSS. CSS is currently not supported by
>   gtkhtml (the part that Evolution uses
>   to display HTML). This will likely be
>   fixed in version 3.2 when Evolution
>   will use WebKit instead of gtkhtml.

http://live.gnome.org/Evolution/FAQ#Why_does_Evolution_not_correctly_display_some_HTML_emails.3F

Also, it seems that the market share of Evolution is somewhere below 1%.

Comment: yeah, I've seen that. But the background color specified in css for the td's _is_ being rendered, so it would appear there is some support.

Comment: Hm, that's strange. I did not really have much experience with Evolution, I have never checked my emails in that particular client... also there is quite a lack of docs on the web.

Answer (score 1):

It IS possible to style text for Evolution!

I used Evolution for a while (and it sucks), and i succeeded to create a signature for my emails.

I don't exactly remember how i did it, but i do recall i had to write HTML 4.01 Transitional. At the time, i investigated and experimented a little, and it seemed that HTML 4.01 Transitional had the best support and most uniform appearance across the email clients.

Unfortunately (for you) i stopped using Evolution a few months ago and i don't have the code anymore. Sorry.